# masonry not working when the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I put these code at the last lows before `</body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
            // options
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            columnWidth: 230
        });
        $grid.masonry(); //not work

        function test() {
            $grid.masonry(); //it work
        }
</script>
```

when I run the page, show this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3OgW.jpg  masonry is not working.

Now I change the webbrowser(chrome/IE/Firefox)width, is work. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZumGW.jpg

So, I create a function name test with code " $grid.masonry();" and run it, it work.

I'm surprised that the javascript will run after the page has load ready  as unually, but here i must  run the function test manually to achieve it.

what’s going on?

/************************ and  still not working ***************************/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
                // options
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                columnWidth: 230
            });
            $grid.masonry(); // not work
            console.log('the code is running!'); // it work
        });

        function test() {
            var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
                // options
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                columnWidth: 230
            });
            $grid.masonry(); // it work
        }
    </script>
```

/*****************************************************************/

OK,I found a way to resolved it but not elegant. like this:

```
var timeId = setTimeout(function() {
    $grid.masonry();
}, 100);
```

Comment: Try wrapping above code in `$(document).ready(function(){//code here})`

Comment: Thanks, i had try it, but still not working.

Comment: If you found answer to your own question post it as answer and be specific about what you want in this question you just state what happened